Infinite carousel weird behavior when moving faster
I wanna make something like a infinite carousel with "moving circle". It does work but I wanna that the circles move faster when I hover over the left field. That does work also but it have a weird behavior: it looks like there is another line of circles that move faster the whole time and one that moves normal, and when I hover over the field, the "normal" circles are invisible and the faster-moving ones are visible and when I move out it's vice versa.
(I hope you guys understand what I mean.)
I would like that the circles move faster when I hover over the field, but without this strange behavior.


var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var one = document.querySelector("#one");
var two = document.querySelector("#two");

left.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  one.style.animationDuration = "10s";
  two.style.animationDuration = "10s";
})

left.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  one.style.animationDuration = "30s";
  two.style.animationDuration = "30s";
})
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #f80606);
  z-index: 10;
}

.moving-circles {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 24px -128px;
  padding: 24px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.first-row {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 30s slide infinite linear;
}

.first-row a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.first-row span {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 40px;
}
<nav class="moving-circles">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="first-row" id="one">
    <a href="#">
      <span>0</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>3</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>4</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>5</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>6</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>7</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>8</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>9</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="first-row" id="two">
    <a href="#">
      <span>0</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>3</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>4</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>5</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>6</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>7</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>8</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>9</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="move-faster.js"></script>




It is likely the mouseover/out are not triggered in the way you expect

No, I don't think so. The mouse over/out is triggered like I expect, when my mouse is in the left field the circles do move faster and when I am out they move slower, but the behavior is very weird. Can you run the code and look like they behave?

You should use mouseenter and mouseleave instead...

I guess this behavior is because of both animations (duration 30s and duration 10s) are actually started at the same time. So when switching from one to the other it just re-calculates the current translateX position based on the elapsed time. So every 10s the "duration 10s" animation is always on a multiple of -100%, but the "duration 30s" is always on a multiple of -33,33%, no matter when you switch to one of them.

Thank you Martin Schneider! This makes sense. Do you have an idea how to avoid this or do a "workaround"?

You should have a look on -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73764110/how-to-create-infinite-carousel-in-javascript/73765067#73765067

If you want to do it with css only, you need to use one more <div>, which will have a speeded upanimation, but on a pause. And on hover you will start it. You may also need more duplicate .row.
Something like this:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 auto 0 -128px;
  width: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #f80606);
  z-index: 10;
}

.moving-circles {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 24px 0;
  padding: 24px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  &:has(.left:hover) {
    .rows-wrapp {
      animation-play-state: running;
    }
    .rows {
      animation-play-state: paused;
    }
  }
}

.rows-wrapp {
  animation: 5s slide infinite linear paused;
  display: flex;
}

.rows {
  display: flex;
  animation: 10s slide infinite linear;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  a {
    margin: 0 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-33.333%);
  }
}
<nav class="moving-circles">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="rows-wrapp">
    <div class="rows">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#">0</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
        <a href="#">7</a>
        <a href="#">8</a>
        <a href="#">9</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#">0</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
        <a href="#">7</a>
        <a href="#">8</a>
        <a href="#">9</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#">0</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
        <a href="#">7</a>
        <a href="#">8</a>
        <a href="#">9</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>




Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted!
Seems like you are a real CSS expert! May I ask for a contact to you to chat and ask some more CSS questions (maybe your Discord user, if you use Discord)?
